# Implementation of strcpy function

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
char *strcpy_(char *dst, char *src)
{
  while((*src++ = *dst++)!= '\0')
  return src;
}
main()
{
  char src_str[] = "C programming language";
  char dst_str[100];
  printf("dst_str:%s\n", strcpy_(dst_str, src_str));
}
```

When ever i run this function the output of this is " programming language" C goes missing, what is happening here, and i have one more question i don't want to use array for passing the arguments for the function mean i don't want to use `char src_str[] = "C programming language"` or `char dst_str[100]` Instead of this i want to use a pointer like `char *src_str = "C programming language"` and `char *dst_str` , if i use so i get a segmentation error.

Comment: You seem to be copying dest to src !

Comment: You also forgot to put a semicolon or braces after the while. Currently, the return is being ru inside the while.

Comment: You do not need the `!= '\0'` part. The `while` loop will bail when that condition is met.

Answer (score 8):

In addition to copying in the wrong direction, you are missing a semicolon at the end of the `while` loop:

```
char *strcpy_(char *dest, char *src) {
    char *orig = dest;
    while((*dest++ = *src++)!= '\0')
        ; // <<== Very important!!!
    return orig;
}
```

Without the semicolon, which represents an *empty statement*, you execute `return` after copying your first character, which is, of course, incorrect.

Finally, you can skip the check for zero in the header of the loop, like this:

```
while(*dest++ = *src++)
    ;
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure `*dest++` and `dest` should be `*dst++` and `dst`.

Answer (score 1):

You overwrite the source string with the destination string. You probably want it the other way round:

```
(*dst++ = *src++)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning *dst* into *src*, instead of the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be copying `dest` to `src` ! Note that if you had used a more appropriate function prototype then the compiler would have caught this mistake:

```
char * strcpy(char *dest, const char *src); // <<< note the `const` !!!
```

You're also missing a `;` for your while loop.